# add service reference xamarin PCL

Tags: wcf, xamarin

I am trying to consume a WCF service from a Portable Class Library in Xamarin. 
I am using Visual Studio 2015.

https://mallibone.com/post/integrating-a-wcf-service-in-xamarin.forms

describes that this should be possible and that you can even create the proxy using the 'Add Service Reference' after I right click on references.

however, 'Add Service Reference' is not available. I also have tried to generate the Proxy using SLSVCUtil but than I get a lot of errors seeing that there is no System.ServiceModel available.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check out the official guide on using WCF with X.Forms: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/wcf/

Also if you change your PCL profile to Profile 78, then you will have System.ServiceModel reference in PCL.

EDIT:

Changing profiles, oddly, is easier in Xamarin Studio (XS) than Visual Studio (VS).

In XS, just open the Project Options for your PCL and select Build->General on the left, then click the "Change" button next to ".NET Portable", then in the "Current Profile" drop down, select Profile 78.

In VS open the Project Properties for your PCL and select "Library" on the left, then click the "Change" Button. Since you can not just select a profile number you will have to select/unselect the correct Targets to get PCL Profile 78. The below image shows what to select for PCL profile 78:

[image]

Comment: How to change profile as i am not able to view System.ServiceModel

Comment: Edited Answer adding how to chance the PCL Profile.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why this didn't fixed with visual studio xamarin but 
this will help you

- right click ( you can't see Service Ref. )

[image]

1. Open Folder in file Explorer
2. right click ~~~.csproj file edit txt ( notepad or notpad++ whatever you used )
3. search for Frameworkprofile like this
   [image]

change it to **78**
like this

[image]

4. save your edit then automatic your solution will request to reload

[image]

5. finally right click in project sol. you will found Service Ref.

[image]

but i don't know why it's not solved from visualstudio
hope it help