# How to add a service reference to Xamarin PCL on VisualStudio 2017

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a simple Xamarin cross-platform mobile application that needs to connect to a WEB Service. There are a few posts (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044383/adding-service-reference-to-portable-class-library), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705096/in-a-vs2017-xamarin-cross-platform-project-how-do-i-add-a-web-service-reference) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010229/add-service-reference-xamarin-pcl)) saying that Visual Studio doesn't support Service References for Windows Phone 8.1 and that I must remove such target from the project.

Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to do so under VS2017 Community (Release 15.1 26403.7): see image [Visual Studio 2017 doesn't show any Windows 8.1 Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCI3z.jpg). "Windows Phone 8.1" is indeed in the targets but when I click on "Change" it doesn't appear... so I can't remove it.

I know I can add a reference to each platform-specific project (Android or iOS) but the whole point is to rely on a *single* common service reference and avoid time-consuming interfaces.

Thank you for your help!

Andrej

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All my apologies, I have found the answer - like, 45 seconds after posting - by putting together [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84642/cannot-remove-windows-phone-silverlight-in-visual-studio) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010229/add-service-reference-xamarin-pcl):

- Manually edit the portable .csproj
- In the "TargetFrameworkProfile" enter "Profile78"

VS2017 will reload the project and you will now be able to add a Service Reference.

Comment: For me **Profile78** didn't work, but **Profile7** works fine